# AWS. Accidently block all connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I got an EC2 instance. And by some chance, I remote to the instance and set firewall to block all connection from outside. After that, I instantly got kicked out from remote screen. No matter how I tried to connect again, it wont work. So please anyone guide me through this circumstance =( Tks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manage firewall related things inside the instance, the best way to handle such thing is the [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). So you can step back if did something bad happend and also you can control security group rule from the AWS console.

[image]

**Security groups: Security groups act as a firewall for associated Amazon EC2 instances, controlling both inbound and outbound traffic at the instance level.**

[VPC_Security](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html)

if the firewall block all public connection and allow connection within VPC,

Now come to your issue, so you can check [restore-network-connectivity-windows](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restore-network-connectivity-windows/)

**Issue**

> I accidentally disabled network connectivity in Windows while I was
>   working on it, and I’ve lost connection to my Amazon EC2 instance. How
>   can I fix it?

**Short Description**

> You can create a temporary Elastic Network Interface (ENI) and attach
>   it to your instance. This will allow you to connect to the instance
>   temporarily and fix the issue.

Comment: Tks guy, exactly what Im looking for. Many thanks to you.